# (python) como eu coloco o for dentro do def

Tags: python, for

```
numero_sorte = 3
n_tentativas = 4

for rodada  in  range(1,n_tentativas):
  tentativa_2 = input ('qual o numero secreto? ')
  tentativa_2= int (tentativa_2)
  def jogo_adivinha(chute):
    if numero_sorte == chute:
      print('parabens vc acertou')
    elif numero_sorte < chute:
      print('o numero secreto e menor que isso')      
    elif numero_sorte > chute :
      print('o numero secreto e maior que isso')
```

esse é meu código

Comment: Sabe a diferença entre um laço de repetição e uma subrotina?

Answer (score 0):

Amigo, segue o que você quer fazer, para sua dúvida eu coloquei abaixo e comentei como colocar o for dentro da função. Lembrando que o Python trabalha com endentação, talvez não tenha endentado corretamente.

```
import sys

numero_sorte = 3
n_tentativas = 4

def jogo_adivinha(chute):
    if numero_sorte == chute:
      print('Parabens vc acertou')
      sys.exit()
    elif numero_sorte < chute:
      print('o numero secreto e menor que isso\n')
    elif numero_sorte > chute :
      print('o numero secreto e maior que isso\n')

for rodada  in  range(0,n_tentativas):
  tentativa = int(input ('Qual o numero secreto ? '))
  #chama a funcao
  jogo_adivinha(tentativa)

print('Você perdeu\n')

#For dentro da função    
'''

def Teste():
    for x in range(0,3):
        print('passou por aqui: '+str(x))

#Chama funcao
Teste()

'''
```

Answer (score -1):

Python é uma linguagem que não possui delimitadores de bloco, como C por exemplo, por isso a indentação faz parte do seu código. Para que o código esteja associado a uma função, estrutura ou laço é necessário dar um espaço de tabulação.
Para colocar o for na função é necessário fazer da seguinte maneira:

```
funcao():
    for i in valores:
        condicao
```